# How do I start the pylons web application programmatically?

Tags: debugging, pylons, startup

Normally, we start a pylons web application via command line:

```
pastser serve --reload development.ini
```

I wanna know can we start it programmaticly? In a python script file?

I want this because I can start it in IDE, and use the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a job for a shell script - you could launch it from a Python script, but a shell script is likely to be cheaper in terms of mental effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from paste.script.serve import ServeCommand
ServeCommand("serve").run(["--reload", "development.ini"])
```

...some IDEs (e.g. pydev) won't support breakpoints in debug mode if you have `--reload` enabled.  Simply remove it from the list you pass to `.run()` to disable the reload functionality and enable IDE breakpoints.